# Why are my webform conditionals not always working?

Tags: 7, webforms

We have 2 partially same webforms with conditional fields, opening a number of components depending on the selection with radio buttons. When logged on as administrator, both forms work fine. when logged on as simple user, only one webform all works fine, the other shows all components as it were designed.

We did recreate the conditionals already and the permissions are same on both forms.  Also no error message is generated in any way.
Anyone has similar problem or has ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As our native language is Belgian Dutch and we use a comma for decimal separator, I added a simple replacement for comma to dot in webform_calculations.js.
 This resulted initially in a javascript error for empty fields, and meanwhile the code was reproduced in Drupal's default files.
 Since only one webform has calculated fields only that form was affected when logged on as user.
 After correction a new file was generated and strange enough only administrator login used it, so all worked fine, while the user logon kept using the faulty file, even after all cache cleaning (Drupal and browser) and rebuilding.
Replaced all files with correct code..
Problem solved.